# How do I "capture" and store the complex output of a Flutter function as code so I can write unit tests for it?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

First of all, apologies if this is a stupid question. I'm new to unit tests so I'm struggling a bit here.

I'm working on an app that queries an API, receives a JSON response and then processes that response to produce a series of complex data structures. Many of these data structures are daily time series, which means each of my functions produces a list (`List<Datapoint>`) containing hundreds of datapoint objects.

What I'm trying to test is that, for a given API response, each function produces the output it should.

For the input of each test I have already grabbed a sample, real JSON response from the API, and I've stored it inside a `test_data` folder within my root `test` folder.

However, for the `expect` part... how can I obtain a sample output from my function and store it somewhere in my `test_data` folder?

It would be straightforward if the output of my function were a string, but in this case we're talking about a list with hundreds of custom objects containing different values inside them. The only way to create those objects is through the function itself.

I tried running the debugger to check the value of the output at runtime, which I can do... but that doesn't help me copy it or store it anywhere as code.

Should I try to print the full contents of the output to a string at runtime and store that string? I don't think this would work, as all I see in the console are a bunch of `Instance Of` when I do `functionOutput.toString()`... I would probably need to recursively print each of the variables inside those objects.

Please tell me I'm being stupid and there's a simpler way to do this :)

Comment: First I'd add `.toString()` methods to your classes as needed so that they generate appropriate output when printed.  Then I would paste all of the output into a text editor, use search-and-replace and/or multi-cursor editing to transform that output into valid Dart code that initializes some global variable, save it as a `.dart` file, and then have your tests `import` it.  I could give you more specific help if you have a more specific example.

Comment: Thanks! When you say add ```.toString()``` methods, you mean override the default one for each class so that it actually prints all its contents as proper strings, right? Good call, hadn't thought of that! I just tried it with one of the classes and I do get a proper print of all the values that way. Why would I need the "search and replace" bit though? Can't I just dump this long string I'm printing right onto a dart file like ```String sampleOutput = "CTRL-V HERE"```? Then I can just import that and compare ```sampleOutput``` to ```output.toString()``` during tests, can't I?

Comment: Yes, that would work too, and comparing the string representations certainly would be a lot easier. (However, it opens the door for ambiguity if you're not careful (e.g. `[[1, 2]].toString() == ['[1, 2]'].toString()`).  For a unit test where you might care only about kicking the tires, that's likely to be good enough.)